# positioning of breadcrumbs isn't correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

On my web page I have a menu and breadcrumbs. In my menu I have 2 sub menus. In my menu my menu items are Design Services, Design Porfolio, Design fees, About us, Contact us, Design resources, design vacancies and terms.
When I click on Design Services a drop down appears. In that drop down there is Graphic Design, Logo design and website design.
When I click on Logo Design a drop down appears. In that drop down I have Corporate identity design, Corporate identty guidelines and fixed fee logo design.

When I click on the menu items the breadcrumbs needs to shift down and when I click on the menu items to make it dissappear the breadcrumbs needs to shift up.

My problem is that when I click on the menu items the breadcrumbs don't shift down and the menu items end up overlapping the breadcrumbs.

My HTML code is

```
 <!-- NAVIGATION SECTION -->
            <div class="navigation-wrapper overlay-bg border-bottom-white padding-level-one">
                <ul class="main-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-active main-menu-sub" href="javascript:void(0);">Design services</a>
                            <div class="main-menu-sub-wrapper">
                                <div class="sub">
                                    <ul class="testing1">
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">graphic design</a></li>
                                        <li><span>/</span></li>
                                        <li><a class="main-menu-sub1" href="javascript:void(0);">Logo design</a>
                                            <div class="main-menu-sub-wrapper1">
                                                <div class="sub1">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Corporate identity design</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Corporate identity guidelines</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Fixed fee logo design</a></li>   
                                                    </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><span>/</span></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Website Design</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Design portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Design fees</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Design resources</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Design vacancies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>  
                        <li class="nav-arrow no-action">
                            <img src="images/nav-arrow-white.png" />
                        </li>
                        <div class="clearboth"></div>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearboth"></div>
            </div>


            <!-- END NAVIGATION SECTION -->
                    <!-- BREADCRUMBS SECTION -->
            <div class="breadcrumbs-wrapper overlay-bg border-bottom-white padding-level-one">
                <div class="breadcrumbs-inner-wrapper">
                    <a href="#">Home</a><span>></span>
                    <a href="#">Design Services</a><span>></span>
                    <a href="#">Logo design</a>
                    <div class="clearboth"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END BREADCRUMBS SECTION -->
```

My jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {


$(".main-level-nav li").hover(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("no-action")) return false;
    $(".main-level-nav").find(".nav-arrow img").attr("src","images/nav-arrow-blue-one.png");
    $(".main-level-nav").find(".nav-arrow").addClass("active");
    $(".main-level-nav").find(".nav-arrow").removeClass("inactive");

},function(){
    $(".main-level-nav").find(".nav-arrow img").attr("src","images/nav-arrow-white.png");
    $(".main-level-nav").find(".nav-arrow").addClass("inactive");
    $(".main-level-nav").find(".nav-arrow").removeClass("active");

});
$(".social-icons-wrapper .twitter-div").hover(function(){
    $(".social-icons-wrapper").find(".nav-arrow img").attr("src","images/nav-arrow-blue-one.png");
    $(".social-icons-wrapper").find(".nav-arrow").addClass("active");
    $(".social-icons-wrapper").find(".nav-arrow").removeClass("inactive");
    $(".twitter-feed").stop().slideToggle( 250 );
},function(){
    $(".social-icons-wrapper").find(".nav-arrow img").attr("src","images/nav-arrow-white.png");
    $(".social-icons-wrapper").find(".nav-arrow").addClass("inactive");
    $(".social-icons-wrapper").find(".nav-arrow").removeClass("active");
    $(".twitter-feed").stop().slideToggle( 250 );
});

$(".additional-navigation a").hover(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("active")) return false;
    $(this).find(".nav-arrow").attr("src","images/nav-arrow-blue-one.png");
    //$(".additional-navigation").find(".nav-arrow").addClass("active");
    //$(".additional-navigation").find(".nav-arrow").removeClass("inactive");
    //$(".twitter-feed").slideDown(200);
},function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("active")) return false;
    $(this).find(".nav-arrow").attr("src","images/nav-arrow-white.png");
    //$(".additional-navigation").find(".nav-arrow").addClass("inactive");
    //$(".additional-navigation").find(".nav-arrow").removeClass("active");
    //$(".twitter-feed").slideUp(200);
});

$(".contact-details-onpage").click(function(){
    if($(".contact-details-onpage-inner").css("display") == "block"){
        $(this).removeClass("active");  
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".contact-details-onpage-inner").stop().slideToggle( 250 );
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");    
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".contact-details-onpage-inner").stop().slideToggle( 250 );   
    }
});

$(".contact-details-onpage-inner a").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
},function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".main-level-nav li").hover(function(){
    if($(this).find("ul:first").length > 0){
        /*$(this).find("ul:first").show();*/
        $(this).find("ul:first").stop().slideToggle( 250 );
    }
},function(){
    if($(this).find("ul:first").length > 0){
        /*$(this).find("ul:first").hide();*/
        $(this).find("ul:first").stop().slideToggle( 250 );
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info1").click(function(){
    if($(".additional-nav-info-inner1").css("display") == "block"){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner1").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner1").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner1 a").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".additional-nav-info2").click(function(){
    if($(".additional-nav-info-inner2").css("display") == "block"){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner2").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner2").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner2 a").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
}); 

$(".additional-nav-info3").click(function(){
    if($(".additional-nav-info-inner3").css("display") == "block"){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner3").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner3").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner3 a").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".additional-nav-info4").click(function(){
    if($(".additional-nav-info-inner4").css("display") == "block"){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner4").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner4").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner4 a").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

$(".additional-nav-info5").click(function(){
    if($(".additional-nav-info-inner5").css("display") == "block"){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner5").stop().slideToggle(250);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".additional-nav-info-inner5").stop().slideToggle(250);
    }
});

$(".additional-nav-info-inner5 a").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeIn(250);
}, function(){
    $(this).find("img").eq(0).fadeIn(250);
    $(this).find("img").eq(1).fadeOut(250);
});

    $("ul.main-menu li").click(function()
    {
      if($(this).find(".sub").length) {
      $(".main-menu").css({"padding-bottom":'15px'});
      $(this).find(".sub").show();

    }
  });

  $("ul.main-menu li").on('mouseleave',function()
  {
    if($(this).find(".sub").length) {
    $(".main-menu").css({"padding-bottom":'0px'});
    $(this).find(".sub").hide();
    }
  });

  $("ul.testing1 li").click(function()
  {
    if($(this).find(".sub1").length) {
    $(".testing1").css({"padding-bottom":'15px'});
    $(this).find(".sub1").show();
    }
  });

  $("ul.testing1 li").on('mouseleave',function()
  {
    if($(this).find(".sub1").length) {
    $(".testing1").css({"padding-bottom":'0px'});
    $(this).find(".sub1").hide();
    }
 });

 });
```

My css code is

```
 .clearboth{
 clear:both;    
 float:none !important;
 display:block;
 height:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

.nav-arrow{
  float:right !important;   
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  margin:5px 0 0 0;
  padding:10px 0;
}

.nav-arrow img{
display:block;  
}

.main-level-nav{
/*padding:10px 0;*/
position:relative;
}

.nav-active{
color:#43b6cf !important;
}
.overlay-bg{
background:url(../images/overlay-bg.png) top left repeat;   
}

 .border-bottom-white{
border-bottom:solid 1px #FFFFFF;
}

.padding-level-one{
padding:0 22px; 
}

.breadcrumbs-inner-wrapper{
padding:10px 0;
}

.breadcrumbs-wrapper a{
display:block;
float:left;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000000;
margin:0 10px 0 0;  
}

.breadcrumbs-wrapper a:hover{
color:#43b6cf;
}
.breadcrumbs-wrapper span{
display:block;
float:left;
margin:0 10px 0 0;
}

.breadcrumbs-wrapper{
}
.testing {

}

.main-menu ul{
  color: red !important;
 /*position: absolute;*/

}

.testing li {
list-style: none;
float: left;

}

.testing a:hover {
color: #43b6cf;
}

.testing a {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0 25px 0 0;
padding: 10px 0;
display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:25px
}
.sub{
  position:absolute;
  padding-top: 5px;
  display:none
}

.sub1{
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to Kishorevarma I have half of what I need done. I'm still having a problem with getting the 2nd submenu to do what I would like it to do.

Comment: The reason your breadcrumbs are at the top is due to the `position: absolute` on your breadcrumb UL, but without a working jsfiddle it is impossible to tell the exact problems you are getting, and what to suggest as a repair.

Comment: My jsfiddle is working. Does something happen when you click on the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use clearfix class in

```
 <div class="navigation-wrapper overlay-bg border-bottom-white padding-level-one main-menu clearfix">
```

and remove absolute position for "ul" tag

```
 .clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
 /* start commented backslash hack \*/
  * html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
 .clearfix { display: block; }
 /* close commented backslash hack */
```

read this to understand clearfix "http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/"

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work. My menu ended up going funny. Here is a link to see what happens [link](jsfiddle.net/32j6Y/2/) click on Design services to see what I mean

Comment: hey add this css  .main-menu-sub-wrapper {position: absolute;}

Comment: Thanks that seems to work but now my breadcrumbs doesn't move down when I click on the menu

Comment: I think this is what you want http://jsbin.com/OvECAQu/3 , http://jsbin.com/OvECAQu/3/edit, this should your problem

Comment: that was what I wanted. I would like to know how you were able to make the breadcrumbs go down. The reason I asked is because I tried to create another submenu with in the 1st submenu and the submenu items go over the breadcrumbs.

Comment: Hey you can see the code here  http://jsbin.com/OvECAQu/12/edit , basically when you mouse over I am giving padding to $(".main-menu").css({"padding-bottom":'+=20'+'px'}); http://jsbin.com/OvECAQu/12  , I have modified the script, now you can add any level deep menus which automatically bring bread crumb down, if you satisfied with answer flag it cheers

Comment: Awesome. That was exactly what I needed. Thanks sooooooo much Kishorevarma

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute` from `.main-menu ul` styles.

Comment: If I do that then my menu goes funny. Here is a link to see what happens when I remove  position:absolute [link](http://jsfiddle.net/32j6Y/1/)

Comment: click on design services.

Comment: Hmm... does it help if you add the `position:absolute` to `.main-menu>ul>li` instead?

Comment: It didn't everything ended up being on top of each other